# C++, GTK+, and String types

Tags: c++, string, gtk

Excuse my ignorance here but I know neither C++ nor GTK+.

Which String type is used when setting Strings in GTK+ widgets?

In .NET, Strings passed to a control are obviously .NET System.String. In Cocoa, Strings passed to a control are NSString. But I understand C++ does not have a standardized String type (but indeed several, depending on the library used).

So how are Strings passed to GTK+ widgets?

(I am thinking C Strings, but I want to know for sure.)

Comment: By the way, you may want to check out the *STL* (**Standard** Template Library) for a class called `std::string`.  I believe this is considered as a "standardized C++ String type".  As you have discovered, there is no *universal* string library.

Comment: Try Vala: [http://live.gnome.org/Vala] it is new language for GTK+ which produces native code and its better designed than C++ (IMHO).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All text in GTK+ is UTF-8-encoded, using `char *`, of course `const` where possible. Remember that GTK+ is implemented in C, so there is no use of STL for instance.

The underlying glib's [character-set conversion documentation](http://www.gtk.org/api/2.6/glib/glib-Character-Set-Conversion.html#id3028573) begins by stating:

> Glib uses UTF-8 for its strings, and
>   GUI toolkits like GTK+ that use Glib
>   do the same thing.

Comment: I am assuming that this is true and it was pretty much what I expected. Ta.

Answer (score 2):

Note that if you are using Gtk+ in C++, even though it's possible to use the native C interface, you definitely should be using [Gtkmm](http://www.gtkmm.org/en/), the native C++ binding instead. It's a far better interface, as you don't have to mess with any GObject code.